# Java Generics - Method overriding

Tags: java, generics

I have a pair of classes ClassA & ClassB as shown below.
case 1:

```
class ClassA<T extends Number>{
    void method(T t){}
}

class ClassB extends ClassA<Integer>{
    @Override
    void method(Integer i){}
}
```

case 2:

```
class ClassA{
    void method(Number t){}
}

class ClassB extends ClassA{
    @Override
    void method(Integer i){}
}
```

I have two questions here.
[q1]
Am I right if I say that, case2 is the runtime representation of case1(after type erasure)?

[q2]
If I am right about [q1], then why the case1 is accepted as a valid override? (I know why case2 is not a valid override since the parameters are not same.)

Someone please shed some light on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `case 1`, it is specified that `T` is `Integer`, therefore overriding with `T = Integer` is valid. But `Number` is not `Integer`, that would work if it was `<? extends Number>`. Or at least that might work, I'd need to check.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer to [q1] is no.
The compiler will generate a *bridge* method in the `ClassB` that will actually overide the `method(Number)`.

```
class ClassB extends ClassA{
    // bridge method
    void method(Number i){
        method((Integer)i);
    }

    void method(Integer i){}
}
```

You will have the complete answer in the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) on type erasure.

Answer (score 1):

In Java (since version 5) the return types of an overridden methods have to be covariant and the parameters of the overridden methods have to be contravariant.

That means that the overriding class can be more specific in what it returns and more accepting in what it receives.

In your 2nd example imagine a variable of the type `ClassA` with an instance of the `ClassB` as a value.

```
 ClassA a = new ClassB(); // This is legal, since ClassB is a subclass of ClassA
 a.method(1.0); // This is legal, since ClassA.method accepts Number
```

The other way however would be ok:

```
public class ClassC { public Number method(Integer i) {...} }
public class ClassD extends ClassC {
   @Override 
   public Integer method(Number n) {...}
}
```

is valid, because the `ClassD` still fulfills the contract defined by `ClassC`.

Comment: -1, sorry. This is wrong: parameter-types of overridden methods must match *exactly*. Contravariance does not suffice. Your example code will not compile.

Comment: `ClassA a = new ClassB(); a.method(1.0);` only works because of a raw type. (It will throw a `ClassCastException`.) Furthermore method overrides in Java do **not** allow contravariant parameters.

Comment: You are right. A bridge method has to created for contravariant arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The actual superclass of `ClassB` is `ClassA<Integer>`. Therefor its member function `method` has the compile-time signature:

```
void method(Integer t){}
```

You can convince yourself by invoking something like

```
ClassA a = new ClassB();
a.method(1.0);
```

You should see a runtime error. In fact it is only possible to compile this, because I used the erased version of `ClassA`. In fact every assignment to a 
generic type other than `ClassA<Integer>` (e.g. `ClassA<Number`>) would fail due to incompatible types.